# iOS (Swift): Location of touch event in UIButton programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, touch

I have a `UIButton` instance that I want to get the exact location of the touch even that triggers the selector attached to it.

The button is configured as follows:

```
private var button: UIButton!

private func setupButton() {
    button = UIButton(frame: frame)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc private func buttonPressed(_ button: BounceButton) {
    // I need the location of the touch event that triggered this method.
}
```

What is the method for achieving the location of the touch event that triggered the `buttonPressed` method, please? I'm hesitant to use a `UIGestureRecognizer` instance as I actually have multiple buttons with different `tag` values that I use to do different things within the `buttonPressed` method.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
  if let touch = touches.first {
     let position = touch.location(in: view)
      if button.frame.contains(position) {

      }
  }
}
```

Option2

add gesture and to access the button use

```
@objc func tapped(_ gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    print(gesture.view?.tag)
    print(gesture.location(in: gesture.view))
}
```

gesture.view

Comment: Thanks. In option 1, `touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)` is not called when the button is touched. Option 2 may be the best solution, thanks.